# Exchange 2010 MailboxDisabled after Storage Quota Reached

Tags: exchange-2010, quota, mailbox

In Exchange 2010 we have found that users are not able to access their mailbox once they hit their storage quota. This is not what we want: we want them to receive a warning, but still be able to get in so that they can clean up their mailbbox, and thus be able to send and receive again.

In the particular instance we encountered today, management approved increasing this user's quota, however once this was done they were unable to access their mailbox. Running the cmdlet `Get-MailboxStatistics` shows that StorageLimitStatus is MailboxDisabled.

Is there a way to prevent this? Also, now that we've upped the quota, how do we re-enable the maailbox? I read somewhere that you had to wait 2 hours; this is not really acceptable, is there no way to manually re-enable it, without rebooting or restarting any roles? (e.g. without causing a disruption to all the other users).

**UPDATE:** A colleague has pointed me in the direction of [this Technet article.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684892%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) However, I'm not able to determine whether this applies to Exchange 2010, and it still doesn't address the issue of forcing a manual refresh without restarting the mailbox database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the StorageLimitStatus to update immediately, you'll have to restart the Information Store service. If this is not an option, try this:

Run

```
Clean-MailboxDatabase [MBDatabaseName]
```

and then

```
Connect-Mailbox [UserName] -Database [MBDatabaseName]
```

Don't worry, the Clean-MailboxDatabase doesn't "clean" as in remove anything. It just updates disabled/disconnected mailboxes in the Exchange Store